# Adding T9 text input in KaiOS

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, kaios

I'm trying to build a simple KaiOS app with a text input but I can only insert numbers (numbers of the phone keyboard). Is there a way to write characters (like a specific input type)?

For example : if the <kbd>2</kbd> is pressed twice it prints `B`, or even better having the T9 feature and write `hello` with 43556 pressed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're still on this issue (I doubt but it can help others). I had the same problem and actually, the emulator doesn't work very well and doesn't really trigger keys. So just use your own keyboard or test directly on the device.

Comment: Yes i actually had the answer from the KaiOS team, the simulator doesn't handle well the keyboard inputs so it's advised to use a real phone to test

Comment: Have you launched your app? I tried but I can not access the app submission platform.. The KaiOS ecosystem product seems a bit tricky/broken in some parts

Comment: Not yet, but i know that you have to contact theme directly and pay (the price depends) to have a presence inside their app store (very different from Android or iOS way of thinking). It's quite restrictive to have only good quality apps inside their app store

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to switch to a different input mode?

If I remember correctly, that could be done by pressing the <kbd>#</kbd> button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using the kaiosrt emulator and pressing # doesn't trigger anything. I've also tried many input types (phone, email, text...) but none seems to allow me to write as a normal kaios phone should (eg: 2 presses on '2' give the letter 'b')